# Conduit: make a Source from another Source

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am having source crawling some websites and collects items of type `Category` from them:

```
catsSource :: Source IO Category
```

The next step is to write companies collector (items of type `Company`). Companies collector needs categories: for each `Category` on input several companies should be produced, one by one. In other word it should "yield" `Company`, not `[Company]`.
What do I need for this task? Conduit or tricky source? If source, how it should get categories from `catsSource`? If conduit how it should pass ("yield") company forward when it is found?

To clear my question here is an attempt (not passing type check):

```
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

companiesFromCategory cat = [Company "foo", Company "bar"]

companies :: Conduit Category IO Company
companies = CL.fold . (CL.map companiesFromCategory)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `concatMap`:

```
companies = CL.concatMap companiesFromCategory
```